# what is the mistake in the mergesort code

Tags: javascript, merge, mergesort

```
function mergesort(arr, left, right) {
    if (left < right) {
        let mid = parseInt((right - left) / 2) + left;
        mergesort(arr, left, mid);
        mergesort(arr, mid + 1, right);
        merge(arr, left, mid, right);
    }
}

function merge(arr, left, mid, right) {
    let i = left, j = mid + 1, k = 0, temp = [];
    while (i <= mid && j <= right) {
        if (arr[i] <= arr[j]) {
            temp[k] = arr[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } else {
            temp[k] = arr[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    for (; i <= mid; i++) {
        temp[k] = arr[i];
        k++;
    }
    for (; j <= right; j++) {
        temp[k] = arr[j];
        k++;
    }
    for (let i = left; i <= right; i++) {
        arr[i] = temp[i];
    }
}

let arr = [ 5, 3, 7, 2, 9, 12, 4 ];
n = arr.length;
mergesort(arr, 0, n);
```

Please help me to find the bugs in the `mergesort` code.
It prints this output: `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 3, 5]`. Why it is not working properly.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: off by 1 error...

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the last `for` loop, copying the `temp` array back to the `arr` slice: you use the same index `i` in both arrays whereas you should use two different index variables to index into `temp` from `0` to `k` excluded and into `arr` from `left` to `right` inclusive.

Here is a modified loop:

```
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        arr[left + i] = temp[i];
    }
```

Note also these remarks:

- to perform integer division by 2, you should use `(right - left) >> 2` instead of converting to a string and parsing back as an integer, a much more costly operation.
- copying  the remaining elements from `arr` to `temp` in the penultimate `for` loop is useless since these elements are already in the proper place.
- you pass `n` to the initial call as the `right` index: this is inconsistent with your `mergesort` function semantics that expects `right` to be the index to the last element, not one past it.

It is actually more idiomatic in javascript and similar languages with `0` based arrays to consider `right` to be the latter (index past the last element). Here is a modified version with this semantic change:

```
function mergesort(arr, left, right) {
    if (right - left > 1) {
        let mid = left + ((right - left) >> 1);
        mergesort(arr, left, mid);
        mergesort(arr, mid, right);
        merge(arr, left, mid, right);
    }
}

function merge(arr, left, mid, right) {
    let i = left, j = mid, k = 0, temp = [];
    while (i < mid && j < right) {
        if (arr[i] <= arr[j]) {
            temp[k++] = arr[i++];
        } else {
            temp[k++] = arr[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < mid) {
        temp[k++] = arr[i++];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        arr[left + i] = temp[i];
    }
}

let arr = [ 5, 3, 7, 2, 9, 12, 4 ];
mergesort(arr, 0, arr.length);
```